# Cannot upload extensions manually

Tags: extensions, file-permissions, file-upload

I keep getting errors when trying to upload to my `tmp` directory, it always fails if I try by URL or upload. The only way it works is via a direct upload Joomla extension.

As I have root access I have made sure permissions and ownership are correct and that the file path to my `tmp` folder is correct in global of admin as well as `configuration.php` so I am trying to figure out why it keeps failing.

I have `chown apache:root` on all my Joomla folders with permissions 755 and the path is `mysite.com/joomla` as it is in a sub-directory but all else works except for this. Also I noticed each time I do an install it fails to create the `configuration.php` file. Have I got ownership and permissions correct?

### Update

The error was a number of things coming up but the main thing persisting that I remember and that is still there is `tmp` file folder not writable. I ended up clearing the cache via command and since then everything works but this one error message on `tmp` folder remains in warnings.

Further to this I reinstalled latest 3.6 with exact same ownership and permissions but used wget command for tar file and now it is all working no errors.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "by url or upload"?

Comment: when you choose option to upload via a url address or via a folder locally.

Answer (score 1):

Open your apache configuration file and add these lines of code:

```
User apache
Group root
```

The file may be located in `/etc/apache2` directory for example `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

As an alternative you may consider changing the ownership of files/folders to `www-data:www-data` recursively because this is the default user/group of apache:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data YOUR_JOOMLA_BASE_DIR
```

Comment: used to working with drupal and always set folders apache:root and 755 which always worked...is joomla different ?

Comment: none of the above works but thanks.

Comment: It's weird. These solutions have worked for all of my local projects. BTW I forgot to mention that when you use the first method, you must restart the apache server (`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`) or for the second method you must be a super user (type `sudo ` before `chown`). Maybe this solve the issue.

Comment: yes i did all that but on mine its service httpd restart  - so i am just using the joomla ext to upload and having to avoid any upload from url or local files.

Comment: plus on centos it is actually apache:root that needs to be ownership and you never declare this in /etc/httpd/conf.d/conf file

Comment: will have to keep this open because joomla continues to warn no access to tmp folder and only allow upload within system.

Comment: Double check the user/group: `egrep -ri '^user|^group' /etc/httpd`. Plus some people add the directory write permission for group so try chmod 775 for `tmp` folder. Moreover, if you found the solution, please add it as an answer. Also please add the "error message" in your question.

Comment: Also some people use 660 for file and 770 for directory permissions on CentOS: [centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1063](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1063#p6547). Then restart the server: `sudo service httpd restart`

Comment: It inexplicably started working maybe after clearing server cache, I don't know. I hate leaving questions unanswered in here but honestly don't know if as simple as cache or not.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for sharing your findings. It may help people with similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

is the command used in centos to completely clear caches and after that still got the error but at least everything is working now.